# Is the stock in my unsealed jar safe?

Tags: canning, stock, pressure-canner

I canned beef and chicken stock at 12 PSI for 25 minutes and I left the canner untouched for two days with the lid on.  After the two days, I opened the canner and found that some of the jars didn't seal.  I think it's safe to assume that the canner itself was sealed, so as long as I leave the lid on it, the stock in the unsealed jars are safe.  I could freeze the stock for later or eat it right away.  Is that true?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you had followed correct procedure and found the unsealed jars in a timely manner, [(within 24 hours) you could use or freeze them](https://food.unl.edu/saving-home-canned-food-jars-did-not-seal). You did not, you waited 2 days.

It is generally false that "the canner was sealed" - most pressure canners only seal for pressure, not vacuum, as they are not designed to be a canning jar, but to process them. Thus, when the pressure inside falls below the outside pressure, a vent typically opens to equalize pressure so that the lid can be opened (and so that the canning jars remain sealed.)

Out they go.